# sed problem. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace a[ 'xxx' ] by a[ xxx ] using sed:

```
sed -e 's/a[ '\(.*\)' ]/a[ \1 ]/' ./Test
sed: -e expression #1, char xx: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` and `]` like this:

```
echo "a[ 'xxx' ]" | sed "s/a\[ '\(.*\)' \]/a[ \1 ]/"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about simply deleting the single-quote characters?  To avoid confusing the
shell, use double-quotes around the expression:

```
 sed -e "s/'//g"
```

a['xxx']

a[xxx]

Greg Johnson

Answer (score 0):

What about using `tr` to delete the single quotes?

```
printf "a['xxx']\n" | tr -d "'"
a[xxx]
```